# Application setting is not saved

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings.settings, stringdictionary

I want to save a `StringDictionary` into the Application Settings in order to fill my listbox `lbc_lastCustomersVisited` with saved values at application launch.

Here is my application setting (XML format) :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="Wibe_EFI.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
    <Profiles />
    <Settings>
        <Setting Name="ApplicationSkinName" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
            <Value Profile="(Default)" />
        </Setting>
        <Setting Name="LastTimeWibeDataObtained" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
            <Value Profile="(Default)" />
        </Setting>
        <Setting Name="LastVisitedCustomer" Type="System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary" Scope="User">
            <Value Profile="(Default)" />
        </Setting>
  </Settings>
```

In my form, I got a `StringDictionary` local variable :

```
public partial class MainForm : XtraForm
{
    private StringDictionary lastVisitedCustomers = new StringDictionary();
    [...]
}
```

Here is how I fill my `StringDictionary` local variable :

```
private void btn_selectCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView selectedRow = GetCustomersGridSelectedRow();
    lastVisitedCustomers.Add(GetCustomerID(selectedRow), String.Format("{0} - {1}", GetCustomerName(selectedRow), GetCustomerCity(selectedRow)));
}
```

(*the `StringDictionary` is successfully filled*)

At `FormClosing`, I save my setting :

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        Settings.Default["ApplicationSkinName"] = UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName;
        Settings.Default.LastVisitedCustomer = lastVisitedCustomers;
        Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The setting `ApplicationSkinName` is successfully saved but not the `lastVisitedCustomer StringDictionary`.
Because when I load my settings at application launch time,  `Settings.Default.LastVisitedCustomer` is `null`.

Here is how I load my setting about the application skin (it works) :

```
public MainForm()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        InitSkinGallery();
        UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = Settings.Default["ApplicationSkinName"].ToString();
}
```

But I cannot load my `StringDictionnary` right here because of a `NullReferenceException`. 
So I load it here :

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mySqlCeEngine = new MySqlCeEngine(this);
    ShowHomePanel();
    LoadLastVisitedCustomers();
}

private void LoadLastVisitedCustomers()
{
    if (Settings.Default.LastVisitedCustomer.Count > 0)
    {
        lastVisitedCustomers = Settings.Default.LastVisitedCustomer;
    }
    lbc_lastCustomersVisited.DataSource = new BindingSource(lastVisitedCustomers, null);
    lbc_lastCustomersVisited.DisplayMember = "Value";
    lbc_lastCustomersVisited.ValueMember = "Key";
}
```

But at this moment, `Settings.Default.LastVisitedCustomer` is null and I don't understand why. I tried some things like not using a local variable and read/write directly from `Settings.Default.LastVisitedCustomer` but I got the same problem.

Thanks,

Hellcat.

**EDIT** : Added full `Settings.settings` file (XML view)

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the whole XML file? I think you are accessing the wrong nodes in your `Settings`.

Comment: I edited my post. Thank you !

Comment: Try using `this.LastVisitedCustomers = (StringDictionary)Settings.Default["LastVisitedCustomer"]` in your MainForm() constructor.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but it's still the same : it is null at launch time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution to store a `Dictionary` in the app settings so I decided to deal with a `string` and split it :

```
public partial class MainForm : XtraForm
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> lastVisitedCustomers;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitSkinGallery();
        UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = Settings.Default["ApplicationSkinName"].ToString();
        lastVisitedCustomers = StringToDictionary(Settings.Default["LastVisitedCustomer"].ToString());
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default["ApplicationSkinName"] = UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName;
        Settings.Default["LastVisitedCustomer"] = DictionaryToString(lastVisitedCustomers);
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    #region Dictionary management

    private string DictionaryToString(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
    {
        if (dic.Count == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            string dicString = string.Empty;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dic)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dicString = String.Format("{0} ## {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dicString += String.Format(" -- {0} ## {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }
            return dicString;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> StringToDictionary(string str)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return dic;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] entries = Regex.Split(str, " -- ");

            foreach (string entry in entries)
            {
                string[] kvp = Regex.Split(entry, " ## ");
                dic.Add(kvp[0], kvp[1]);
            }

            return dic;
        }
    }
}
    #endregion
```

For now, it works. 
I hope it will helps anyone in my situation.

**Notice** : You may have to modify my dictionary methods in order to handle every cases for Exceptions. But I think this is okay now. 
*Sorry for any english mistakes*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try, I tried to produce the error you get by creating a new formapplication:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test.Text = (string)Settings.Default["lastCustomers"];
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default["lastCustomers"] = test.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
  }
}
```

In this example the code works. Just create a new Form-Application and add a textbox into it with the name `test`. Every time you close the program and restart it, the string you wrote into the textbox will be saved and reloaded into `test.Text`.

**Specifically in your case your constructor should then look like this:**
(Possible solution)

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitSkinGallery();
    UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = Settings.Default["ApplicationSkinName"].ToString();
    lastVisitedCustomers = (StringDictionary)Settings.Default["LastVisitedCustomer"];
}
```

*Afterwards you save the settings the same way you loaded them:*

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default["ApplicationSkinName"] = UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName;
    Settings.Default["LastVisitedCustomer"] = lastVisitedCustomers;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

This should solve your problem!

**EDIT**
Oh and of course, your loading functions looks different then:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mySqlCeEngine = new MySqlCeEngine(this);
    ShowHomePanel();
    LoadLastVisitedCustomers();
}


private void LoadLastVisitedCustomers()
{
    lbc_lastCustomersVisited.DataSource = new BindingSource(lastVisitedCustomers, null);
    lbc_lastCustomersVisited.DisplayMember = "Value";
    lbc_lastCustomersVisited.ValueMember = "Key";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but it does not solve my problem :(.
I tried your solution, I also tried to use an `OrderedDictionary` instead of the String one. But this is the same : `Settings.Default["LastVisitedCustomer"]` is null at launch time.